# Карточки задач в JS

Tags: javascript

Не знаю с чего даже начать. Нужно вызвать и вернуть `makeTask`. Наверное нужно использовать return? Я только пробую решать задачи. Помогите, пожалуйста.

> Напиши функцию makeTask(data) которая принимает один параметр data - > объект со следующими свойствами.
>
> text - текст задачи.
> category - категория задачи.
> priority - приоритет задачи.
> Функция должна составить и вернуть новый объект задачи, не изменяя напрямую параметр data. В новом объекте должно быть свойство completed, значение которого хранится в одноимённой локальной переменной.
>
> В параметре data гарантированно будет только свойство text, а остальные два, category и priority, могут отсутствовать. Тогда, в новом объекте задачи, в свойствах category и priority должны быть значения по умолчанию, хранящиеся в одноимённых локальных переменных.
>
> ```
> function makeTask(data) {
>   const completed = false;
>   const category = "General";
>   const priority = "Normal";
>   // Change code below this line
>
>   // Change code above this line
> }
> ```

Comment: с чем конкретно возникла проблема?

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки решения задачи

Comment: Я не знаю с чего даже начать. Нужно вызвать и вернуть makeTask.Наверное нужно использовать return? я только пробую решать задачи. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: [Объекты](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) - почитайте и поробуйте сами сделать. Return нужен что бы вернуть результат. Если сделать за вас, вы ничему не научитесь...

Answer (score 2):

Решила

```
function makeTask(data) {
  const completed = false;
  const category = "General";
  const priority = "Normal";
  // Change code below this line
return {...{completed, category, priority},...data}
  // Change code above this line
}
```